# Sub-module dependency injection with constants in Angular

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have an angular app, let's call it Foo. So I have defined 
`angular.module('Foo')`, 
which has also a `constant`, defined as 
`angular.module('Foo').constant('constantObj', {x: 'y'})`.

I have also two sub-modules defined as `angular.module('Baz')` and `angular.module('Moo')` which are injected into `angular.module('Foo')` as:

`angular.module('Foo', ['Baz', 'Moo'])`.

Right now I am getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Foo due to:

[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Baz due to:

[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: constantObj
```

I am trying to use the constant, injecting it in the sub-modules config, but I receive this error message. Anyone can help me with an explanation how can I use a constant in all of the sub-modules, which was defined in Foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some artifact (service, controller, etc) in Baz to use the `constantObj`, Baz must depend on Foo, which *already* depends on Baz. This is a cyclic dependency and Angular will complain.

The solution is to define a third module, say Xxx, define the `constantObj` in it, and have all modules that need `constantObj` also depend on Xxx.

Comment: Thanks Nikos! Instead of define a new module I have changed the dependency chain. So now Baz and Moo depends on Foo, which should have been the correct behavior from the start.